# Running recipe name

Tags: ruby, chef

In Chef, is possible to get the recipe name when this recipe is running?

I want to add recipe name on logging/debugging. Something like:

Chef:Log.info "#{recipe_name} xxxx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually get the recipe name exactly the way you suggested in the question!

```
Chef::Log.info("I am a message from the #{recipe_name} recipe in the #{cookbook_name} cookbook.")
```

This and other handy methods are documented in the [Recipe DSL](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/dsl_recipe.html) page on the Opscode site.

Comment: It's also in chef 10.18.X or only in 11 ?

Comment: Good question - I'm pretty sure I used that in 10.14 (if not earlier), but I don't have it installed somewhere to test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the recipe name, but you can use `__FILE__` to log the filename of the currently executing Ruby script:

```
Chef::Log.info("#{__FILE__}")
```

shows up as

```
[2013-02-13T20:39:10+00:00] INFO: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/gem/recipes/default.rb
```

at least for chef-solo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is an old post, but it is still the top Google result, so I thought an updated answer for Chef 12 would be good to add in.

In Chef 12, I use this directly in my recipe:

```
log("Recipe @ #{__FILE__}")
```

The output looks like this:

```
* log[Recipe @ /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/crafter-cms-dev/recipes/test.rb] action write
```